# SQL Server: adding a calculated column for end date

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime, calculated-columns

I have a data set continuously being updated with date values that looks like this:

```
Part Number Product Status  Phase1  Phase2  Phase3  Phase4  Phase5  Phase6
FD 2000 Maintain    2020-01-03 00:00:00.000 2020-01-08 00:00:00.000 2020-01-15 00:00:00.000 2020-01-17 00:00:00.000 2020-01-22 00:00:00.000 2020-01-31 00:00:00.000
FD 2001 Maintain    2020-01-03 00:00:00.000 2020-01-08 00:00:00.000 2020-01-15 00:00:00.000 2020-01-17 00:00:00.000 2020-01-22 00:00:00.000 2020-01-31 00:00:00.000
```

Basically, the table is made up of a part number and it's respective status and life cycle dates.

Then, I utilize `CROSS APPLY` to get transpose the different phase columns into one column. Here is the SQL syntax:

```
SELECT [Part Number], [Product Status], Phase, Date
FROM PLCMexample
CROSS APPLY (VALUES ('Phase1', [Phase1]),
                    ('Phase2', [Phase2]),
                    ('Phase3', [Phase3]),
                    ('Phase4', [Phase4]),
                    ('Phase5', [Phase5]),
                    ('Phase6', [Phase6]))
            CrossApplied (Phase, Date)
GO
```

This generates this view:

```
Part Number Product Status  Phase   Date
FD 2000     Maintain    Registration Initiation 2020-01-03 00:00:00.000
FD 2000     Maintain    Product Launch  2020-01-08 00:00:00.000
FD 2000     Maintain    Phase Out   2020-01-15 00:00:00.000
FD 2000     Maintain    Last Order  2020-01-17 00:00:00.000
FD 2000     Maintain    Last Shipment   2020-01-22 00:00:00.000
FD 2000     Maintain    Last Service    2020-01-31 00:00:00.000
FD 2001     Maintain    Registration Initiation 2020-01-03 00:00:00.000
FD 2001     Maintain    Product Launch  2020-01-08 00:00:00.000
FD 2001     Maintain    Phase Out   2020-01-15 00:00:00.000
FD 2001     Maintain    Last Order  2020-01-17 00:00:00.000
FD 2001     Maintain    Last Shipment   2020-01-22 00:00:00.000
FD 2001     Maintain    Last Service    2020-01-31 00:00:00.000
```

Which is all well and good, but now I need not only just a `Date` column for the view, but `StartDate` and `EndDate`. The `StartDate` would be the values in the current `Date` column. The `EndDate` would be the same `Date` as the `StartDate` of the following phase. Here's the first six rows of the view as an example of how it should look:

```
Part Number Product Status  Phase   StartDate   EndDate
FD 2000 Maintain    Registration Initiation 2020-01-03 00:00:00.000 2020-01-08 00:00:00.000
FD 2000 Maintain    Product Launch  2020-01-08 00:00:00.000 2020-01-15 00:00:00.000
FD 2000 Maintain    Phase Out   2020-01-15 00:00:00.000 2020-01-17 00:00:00.000
FD 2000 Maintain    Last Order  2020-01-17 00:00:00.000 2020-01-22 00:00:00.000
FD 2000 Maintain    Last Shipment   2020-01-22 00:00:00.000 2020-01-31 00:00:00.000
FD 2000 Maintain    Last Service    2020-01-31 00:00:00.000 2020-01-31 00:00:00.000
```

As you can see, the "Registration Initiation" `EndDate` is the same as the `StartDate` of "Product Launch". The last phase, "Last Service", will have the same `StartDate` and `EndDate`.

What's the best way to handle this? Should I create a calculated column before or after the transposition? This is just a snippet, there are thousands of rows of data just like this so I would like to optimize the code.

Comment: I would recommend changing the data type to DATE, since it appears you're not using the time element of DATETIME (DATETIME2). It will keep it cleaner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want `lead()`:

```
SELECT [Part Number], [Product Status], Phase, Date,
       LEAD(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY [Part Number] ORDER BY Date) as Next_Date
FROM PLCMexample CROSS APPLY
     (VALUES ('Phase1', [Phase1]),
             ('Phase2', [Phase2]),
             ('Phase3', [Phase3]),
             ('Phase4', [Phase4]),
             ('Phase5', [Phase5]),
             ('Phase6', [Phase6])
     ) CrossApplied (Phase, Date);
```

EDIT:

If you want a default value, use the 3-argument form of `LEAD()`:

```
       LEAD(Date, 1, DATEADD(DAY, 100, DATE) OVER (PARTITION BY [Part Number] ORDER BY Date) as Next_Date
```

Comment: This is excellent! It worked quite well. The only caveat is the last phase. Since nothing comes next, it puts a NULL in that column. Is it possible to make that EndDate a certain amount of time after the start date?

Comment: @sykfarhan `ISNULL(LEAD(Date) OVER (PARTITION BY [Part Number] ORDER BY Date), DATEADD(DAY, number_you_want, Date)) as Next_Date` you can do this